# Updating a private variable inside an object using IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

An **object 'person' has a private variable 'name'**. This private variable cannot be updated directly using object reference.

Used IIFE for tackling this. IIFE will return 'name' variable, 'get' and 'update' methods for getting the name and updating it respectively.

```
const person = (function () {
  let name;
  var obj = {};

  init();

  function init() {
    name = 'dravid';
  }

  function getName() {
    return name;
  }

  function modifyName(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }

  Object.defineProperties(obj, {
    'name': {
      value: name,
      writable: false
    },
    'get': {
      value: getName,
      writable: false
    },
    'update': {
      value: modifyName,
      writable: false
    }
  });
  return obj;
})();
```

Let's see below what this code is doing.

```
person.name // returns 'dravid'
person.name = 'dhoni'
person.name // still returns 'dravid'
```

Now, few more...

```
person.get() // returns 'dravid'
person.update('dhoni')
person.get() // returns 'dhoni'
```

Above is pretty much what is required, except for a confusion.

```
person.name // still returns 'dravid' instead of 'dhoni'
```

Why such behavior?

Here's [the link](https://jsfiddle.net/pranjalMT/xgLyjq6h/8/)! to the working code.

Comment: `'name': {value: name}` well, you take it's *value* anyway.

Comment: _[`writable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description): `true` if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator._

Comment: @Andreas this is also not working

Answer (score 2):

The values `name` and `person.name` are not the same or equal. When you execute `Object.defineProperties` and return `obj` you're setting the default value of `person.name` equal to name. But when you call `person.update` you are changing the variable `name`. You are NOT changing the object key `person.name`. If you want to change `person.name` you need to change your `modifyName` method.

```
function modifyName(newName) {
   obj.name = newName;
}
```

Comment: function getName() {
      return obj.name;
    }

    function modifyName(newName) {
      obj.name = newName;
    } Also made writable for name true.